# Write $(r_{1}-r_{2})^{2}(r_{1}-r_{3})^{2}(r_{2}-r_{3})^{2}$ in term of $r_{1}+r_{2}+r_{3}$, $r_{1}r_{2}+r_{2}r_{3}+r_{1}r_{3}$, and $r_{1}r_{2}r_{3}$

Tags: polynomials

Let $D(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3}) = (r_{1}-r_{2})(r_{1}-r_{3})(r_{2}-r_{3})$.

Let $\sigma _{1}(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})=r_{1}+r_{2}+r_{3}$.

Let $\sigma _{2}(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})=r_{1}r_{2}+r_{2}r_{3}+r_{1}r_{3}$.

Finally, let $\sigma _{3}(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})=r_{1}r_{2}r_{3}$.

Write $D(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})^{2}$ as a polynomial in $\sigma _{1}(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})$, $\sigma _{2}(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})$, and $\sigma _{3}(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3})$.

Do I need to multiply out $(r_{1}-r_{2})^{2}(r_{1}-r_{3})^{2}(r_{2}-r_{3})^{2}$?

Comment: I tried something wrong there. Forgot the $ ^2$ for D

Comment: Oh, that's ok. Thank you for trying :)

Comment: Use the definition of the discriminant, you have to express it in terms of the coefficient of the polynomial (and take the square). A nice answer is there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Answer (score 1):

From Denis' answer, I square his expansion to get
$$(aab+bbc+cca)^2+(abb+bcc+caa)^2-2(aab+bbc+cca)(abb+bcc+caa)\\
=aaaabb+2aaabbc-2aaabbb-6aabbcc-2aaaabc
$$
plus all permutations.  For example, when I wrote $aaaabb$ I meant $a^4b^2+a^4c^2+b^4a^2+b^4c^2+c^4a^2+c^4b^2$.
To build those five types of symmetric polynomials, you have $S=a+b+c, Q=ab+bc+ca, P=abc$, and want to build degree-six polynomials from them.
Your seven options are $S^6,S^4Q,S^3P,S^2Q^2,SPQ,Q^3,P^2$
These are seven linear combinations of the seven symmetric polynomials.  (there are also $aaaaab$ and $aaaaaa$.)
Luckily, only $S^6$ contains $aaaaaa$, and $S^4Q$ is the only other one that contains $aaaaab$.  So those two won't be needed.
Write the other five products of $S,P,Q$ as linear combinations of the symmetric polynomials, and row-reduce them to find the specific linear combination that answers the question.